# C# calling base class constructor confusion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In my asp.net MVC app I am using entity framework and Identity for user authentication. So my DbContext class looks like the following (it works):

```
public class PropertyContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public PropertyContext() : base("name=PropertyBDConnection") { }
         ...
    }
```

I am passing a string to the base constructor of PropertyContext . Therefore, I can assume that IdentityDbContext has a constructor that takes a string as argument.

However in the github repository of asp.net identity ([here IdentityDbContext.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs)) I found the following-

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser> : 
      IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string> 
      where TUser : IdentityUser
{ }
```

No constructor at all.  Certainly I am missing something or looking in wrong place.

Comment: The code you've given for `AppContext` is invalid in various ways - seeing as it's clearly *not* copied and pasted from your real code, we can't tell whether the actual code is only different in irrelevant places, or in crucial parts. Please copy and paste an *actual class* that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The difference you're seeing is because you are using prior version of `Identity` in different version of Asp.net(must be 4.x). The code you referred to on github is latest `Asp.net 5` version and which is why you're seeing this much difference.

Comment: @vendettamit I had a feeling I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed my code. now i have copied from my actual code.

Comment: It would help if you would also show which nuget package you're using - the complete version number - so that we can help you find the actual source.

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1

Comment: It would be worth checking that carefully - look in your NuGet references. But hopefully that will be enough for someone to help you. (This isn't my particular area of expertise.)

Comment: @JonSkeet   It’s okay. I am thrilled that you are commenting in my post. Using so many code from you. Can not thank you enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are looking in a wrong place: according to the documentation, `IdentityDbContext` [has three constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext.), one of which takes a `string`:

- `IdentityDbContext()`
- `IdentityDbContext(DbConnection, DbCompiledModel, Boolean)`
- `IdentityDbContext(String)`

Comment: you are right that's why my code works. Could point to the right repository? I am trying to understand identity internals.

Comment: @AmitHasan I am not sure where to look up the up-to-date source, but if you [enable framework source debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) in Visual Studio and set a breakpoint on the line that calls into the constructor of `IdentityDbContext`, you should be able to step into the source and see the internals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have actually access to the source code, but i want to point out a tricky feature of C# that are Implicit operators: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

since IdentityDBContext, in your linked source, has a constructor that take a DBContextOptions, that class could use an implicit converter to convert from string to an instance of DBContextOptions

here a snippet done for you to explain how this work, that simulate a possible way to achieve what you see, this doesn't mean that actual this is the case, probably you are just pointing to a wrong codebase, but this is a possibility

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public class IdentityDbContext {
        public DbContextOptions Options { get; set; }
        public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions options){
            this.Options = options;
        }
    }

    public class DbContextOptions {
        public string Config { get; set; }

        public DbContextOptions(string config){
            this.Config = config;
        }

        public static implicit operator DbContextOptions(string config) {
            return new DbContextOptions(config);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        IdentityDbContext f = new IdentityDbContext(new DbContextOptions("test")); //it's ok
        Console.WriteLine(f.Options.Config);

        IdentityDbContext f2 = new IdentityDbContext("testWithImplicit");
        Console.WriteLine(f2.Options.Config);
    }
}
```

update:
added a fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aykOqq

Comment: Thanks for the link. The implicit keyword never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

The IdentityDBContext class that your are referring to inherits from another class `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>` which then inherits from DbContext.  Look at line 29 of the above reference file [IdentityDbContext.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs)

Answer (score -1):

`IdentityDbContext<TUser>` inherits from `IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>`, which in turn inherits from `DbContext`. `DbContext` contains the constructor which takes a single string.

Comment: You don't inherit constructors though.

Comment: You cannot skip a `base` constructor and call `base.base(string)`